# How to determine an active VM has a vGPU?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using the following URL to retrieve a virtual guest

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/54947181.json?objectMask=mask[datacenter,status,globalIdentifier,primaryIpAddress,primaryBackendIpAddress,billingItem.categoryCode,billingItem.description,billingItem.createDate,billingItem.orderItem.order.userRecord.username,billingItem.orderItem.order.userRecord.email,users.username,users.email,users.userStatus,operatingSystemReferenceCode,softwareComponents.passwords,operatingSystem,hourlyBillingFlag,localDiskFlag,managedResourceFlag,privateNetworkOnlyFlag,powerState,blockDeviceTemplateGroup.name,blockDeviceTemplateGroup.id,blockDeviceTemplateGroup.blockDevices,blockDevices.diskImage,networkVlans,activeTransactionCount,activeTransactions,consoleIpAddressRecord.type,consoleIpAddressRecord.port,consoleIpAddressRecord.ipAddress.ipAddress,userDataCount,userData]
```

Nothing in this mask indicates that the VSI is a vGPU virtual guest.  What mask must I specify to determine if this VSI has a vGPU?

Answer (score 0):

To know if an active VM has a GPU you can use this rest api:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[virtualGuestId]/getObject?objectMask=mask[billingItem[orderItem[preset[computeGroup]]]]
```

You have to search by preset data.

You will get the following result:

```
"preset": {
                "description": "AC1.8x60x25\r\n",
                "id": 405,
                "isActive": "1",
                "keyName": "AC1_8X60X25",
                "name": "AC1.8x60x25",
                "packageId": 835,
                "computeGroup": {
                    "keyName": "GPU_PUBLIC_INSTANCE",
                    "name": "GPU"
                }
           }
```

Comment: Great thank you.  Is there a way to know the package of a captured image?

Comment: There is not, because the capture image only captures the disc information. You can see the following documentation: http://developer.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_virtual_guest/captureimage